# letsencrypt doesn't let me choose "http" or "https" during installation & "-le-ssl.conf" not showing up - Apache

Tags: ssl, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt

When I install letsencrypt in my Ubuntu server (Apache), it doesn't let me choose either "http" or "https" (which it used to). And I don't see any "-le-ssl.conf" file added to /etc/apache2/site-available/ directory. Please Help!

Comment: Can you please add additional information?  How do you install `lets-encrypt` on your server?  What exactly are you installing?

Comment: I used 

"sudo letsencrypt --apache -d example.com"

Comment: I follow this [digitalocean tutotial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-let-s-encrypt-certificates-for-multiple-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Your link is for **certificate** installation, not installation of letsencrypt.  The command you used is for modifying apache to use the letsencrypt certificate.  And of course, you should change the ending (`example.com`) to your domain name (or IP address).  Keep in mind, you need to be hosting from that machine with a domain.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I need to learn more. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I've to create "-ssl.conf" myself with port number 443